# Show year only on the first axis tick or on change

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a question regarding axis formatting of dates in R plotly.

I want to specify custom date tickformats on my x-axis as follows: `'%a %e %b \n %Y'` But I only want to show the year on the first xaxis tick. As it would be too weird to repeat it for each tick label.

I have the following small example:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  x = as.Date(c('2013-02-04', '2013-04-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-08-07', '2013-10-02')),
  y = c(1,4,5,6,2)
)
plot_ly(data = dt, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = '%a %e %b \n %Y'))
```

[image]

Which is the exact same setup from this javascript [example](https://plotly.com/javascript/tick-formatting/#include-locale-config) where it does work!

[image]

[This](https://medium.com/zyphr-solutions/plotly-date-axis-formatting-dbf349ff7264) post with python also seems to work. So I am not sure now what I am doing wrong in R? Or if this is a bug?

---

Edit: I would like to avoid using ggplotly and directly work with plotly as this provide greater control.

Comment: The need for great control is very unspecific and not justified given the example provided.

Comment: I highlight 2 post in javascript and Python where the functionality works like how I want it to work. But in R this does not happen. Also this is just a minimal example which focuses on the problem that I have with my much complexer real example.

So my example is valid.

Comment: You could extend your x-axis layout specification with appropriate `tickformatstops` to hide the year when zooming in: https://plotly.com/r/tick-formatting/#tickformatstops-to-customize-for-different-zoom-levels (note: tickformatstops given in milliseconds)

Comment: @I_O Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am already using that and the thing is that I do want to show my year. As I have a shiny application where the given data could come from any year. So I would like to show the year at least once in my x-tick labels. (or of course when the year changes) So like the behaviour of the other examples to which I linked

Comment: This behaviour is descibed [here](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels). Why don't you file an issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues)?

Comment: @ismirsehregal aha. Thanks for pointing out. I worked with R so I did not look extensively in the python documentation. I played around some more and looking at the `ploty_json` it seems that plotly R has automatically replaced the `\n` with a `<br/>`. I will open a bug.

Comment: Bug issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2115